# Rails how to automatically associate the objects in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to associate the order obtecj with pdata object in the creation of the order object and after the creation of the pdata oject.

but after the creation the order did not get the pdata_id

someone know how do to this?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :pdata

  after_create :create_pdata

  def create_pdata 
    or_id = order.id
    pr_id = product.id

    data = Pdata.find_by_id(pr_id)
    if data.nil?
      attrs = product.attributes
      attrs.delete('created_at')
      attrs.delete('updated_at')
      data = Pdata.create(attrs)

      data = data.or_id

      data.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :pdata

  # only initialize pdata when :pdata is not yet set (this can happen on `create` or on `update`). Change `before_save` to `before_create` if necessary.
  before_save :initialize_pdata, unless: :pdata

  def initialize_pdata
    # initialize `pdata` with the attributes of the `product` record, only except `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `id`. Remove `id` below if you also want to copy the `id`.
    # this method is called at `before_save`, so even if this is just initialised at the moment, when already "saving", this will also save / persist this initialised `pdata` object into the DB.
    self.pdata = Pdata.new(
      product.attributes.except('created_at', 'updated_at', 'id')
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: @bookaka glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
unless data.nil
end
```

OR

```
if data.present?
end
```

Comment: well shows:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pdata.id: INSERT INTO

Comment: You need to delete `id` from attrs

Comment: Sorry Deepak i did not get it

Comment: dele id from attrs?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method to this

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :pdata

  after_create :create_pdata

  def create_pdata 
    pdata = Pdata.find_by_id(product)
    unless pdata
      attrs = product.attributes.slice(:list, :of, :attributes. :you, :want)
      pdata = Pdata.create(attrs)
      self.pdata = pdata
      self.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you Deepak but i'm trying yo associate with order too, can i with your method?

Comment: yes `self.pdata = pdata` will associate it with order

Comment: should i  add the order.id to the method?

Comment: I think @Jay-Ar Polidario has a good answer that may be helpful